# Angular 2 Pass string argument to component

Tags: angular, typescript, components

My target is to pass string arguments to component. Example: I have component that holds and show title and subtitle. I want to pass that strings when I am setting the selector. Something like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'title-subtitle',
})
```

in html:

```
<title-subtitle title="My title" subtitle="My subtitle"></title-subtitle>
```

Comment: check this live plnk. it may help you http://plnkr.co/edit/LEtEN9?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly my answer tho :p.
To be specific, you can't just pass a string argument like you want. You can use the Parent to Child communication from Angular2 which uses an `@Input` where you can send an `Object` with its properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parent component :**

```
<title-subtitle [childInput]="parentInput">
</title-subtitle>

private parentInput: any;
```

---

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.parentInput = 'Hello World';
}
```

**Child component :**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() private childInput: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    // When the data is passed instantly, you can access it here.
    // You can also use {{childInput}} in your HTML
    console.log(this.childInput);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    // When the data is async : get the changes when they are ready

    // Get @Input data when it's ready
    if (changes.childInput) {      
       console.log(changes.childInput.currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Note the naming of the properties in the parent HTML.

N.B : You only need the OnInit and/or OnChanges events when you actually need to do something with your data (i.e. Deep cloning it, ...). If you only display it in your HTML with interpolation, there is no need for the events.

N.B 2 : Be aware that this is the **SAME OBJECT** (same reference) that is sent to your child, which means that if you update a property of your object in your ChildComponent, the changes will also affect the parent. Usually you clone your object to avoid that kind of behavior in the OnInit or OnChanges events.

Answer (score 5):

To pass a string using @input from a parent component to child component there are two ways.

If you want to pass the string,

```
<child-component childInput="child input"> </child-component>
```

If you want to pass the variable from parent component to child component,

```
<child-component [childInput]="parentInput"> </child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you review this [Hero](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-3/ts/eplnkr.html) example it should answer your question

Pay attention to

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

on the **app.component.ts** file